# Connect to Oracle DB as SQL DB

Tags: sql, database

I have a software which works with SQL DB as its local DB; we have ORACLE DB installed and we need to use it instead of SQL, what libraries or adaptors which I can use so the software will see the Oracle DB as SQL DB.

Comment: What SQL DB is? SQL as obviously comes from L is language, which Oracle database supports. You can easily find the documentation on [official website](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client.html) to manage a connection to Oracle DB from your tools.

Comment: Oracle ***is*** a "SQL DB". "SQL" is only a query language and used by every relational database. It's not the name of database product.

Comment: I guess with SQL DB you mean MS SQL Server. This can't be mimiced. You can convert the database (with some effort) to Oracle if it is developed for MS SQL Server but then it will be a Oracle DB afterwards. If your front end application expects a MS SQL Server then there is no other way then installing one.

Comment: Thank you all, sorry I was meaning MS SQL db